# Java- Array Errors

Tags: java

​
I'm new to Java ans struggling with Arrays. I need help with an array code. There are 20 errors but I can't seem to find them (except 7). Also, I'm new to StackOverflow so sorry for the format.
Code is:

```
public clas ArrayProcessing
{
public void main (String [] args)
{
int iElement = 0,
int iSmallest = 0,
int iPossible = 0;
String strElements, strSmallest, strPossibles = "";
strElements = joptionPane.showInputDialog("How many elements would you like to be included in the array?");
iElements= Integer.parseInt(strElements);
strSmallest =joptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like the smallest number in the array to be?");
iSmallest = Integer.parseInt(strSmallest);
strPossibles = joptionPane.showInputDialog("How many possible unique numbers would you like to have?");
iPossibleS= Integer.parseInt(strPossible);
int[] intArray = int[iElement];
displayArray(intArray[0]);
loadArray(intArray, iSmallest, iPossbles)
displayArray(intArray);
}
public static void loadArray(int intArray, int iSmallest, int iPossibles)
{
for (index =0; index < intArray.length(); index++)
{
intArray[index] = iSmallest + (int) (Math.random()* iPossibles);
}
}
public void displayArray(int[] intArray)
{
String strOutput="";
for (iCounter = 0, iCounter<intArray.length, iCounter++);
{
Output += intArray[iCounter] + "";
}
jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These are the values in your array: \n" + strOutput, "Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Have you ever heard of indentation? You know, the concept of making the code readable?

Comment: Since `intArray` is an *array*, perhaps changing `int intArray` to `int[] intArray` in the `loadArray` parameter would help? --- Since your first `for` loop is correctly using `;` between the parts, why are you trying to use `,` in the second one?

Comment: Download an IDE like netbeans or eclipse and paste your code in there. The IDE will point out to you many of the problems in the code.

Comment: **Use an IDE**. That way you can see and fix the coding errors as you make them, rather than wait and get 20 dumped on you later. I hear that [BlueJ](https://www.bluej.org/) is good for beginners.

Comment: Please post your errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

You DEFINITELY need to learn the basics. Get an IDE to display the errors. Eclipse or someone suggested BlueJ (I haven't heard of it) but it will help you. Besides showing errors, it can format your code, too. You can click on the error and it will go to the error line.

1. use semicolons instead of commas.
2. If you have a "{" following a for loop, don't use semicolon.
3. To use swing components (i.e. JOptionPane) you need to have a JFrame to display them in.
4. Indenting is important for YOU and those reading the program. Makes it a lot easier to determine scope.

In a nutshell, you have the concept of programming, but you don't have the basics and you need that first. Start off with an example of, say, JOptionPane and expand on it to include your code.

Good luck. And hang in there. We've all been where you are, but we stuck with it.